# Apply animation on each click not every two

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I am using `Toggleclass` jquery function which toggles `animated wobble` class on each click. How can i animate that button on every click (not every two clicks). [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) on Github.

```js
$("#Bouncebtn").click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventdefault
    $("#Bouncebtn").toggleClass('animated wobble');
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="Bouncebtn" class="shake ">bounce</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for animation end. Hence, you can listen for [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend):

```js
$("#Bouncebtn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#Bouncebtn").toggleClass('animated wobble');
}).on('animationend', function(e) {
    $("#Bouncebtn").toggleClass('animated wobble');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="Bouncebtn" class="">bounce</button>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me inside `.done(function( data ){  })`

Comment: Okay nevermind, some problem on a different example on my own. That's because i use `$("#_table input").on('click', function (e) {` for all inputs in a table

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines of code under the `$("#Bouncebtn").toggleClass('animated wobble');` line. This happens because in thefirst click class is assigned and in the second click class is removed so the animation will now happen.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#Bouncebtn").removeClass('animated wobble');
    }, 1000);
```

```js
$("#Bouncebtn").click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventdefault
    $("#Bouncebtn").toggleClass('animated wobble');
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#Bouncebtn").removeClass('animated wobble');
    }, 1000);
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="Bouncebtn" class="shake ">bounce</button>
```